How to download huge videos from telegram in nodeJS
I was using gramJS to download videos received by my bot. and when I receive huge video files I cannot just use the client.downloadMedia function or I'll run out of memory. so I must stream it.
so I wrote this:
// const message = event.message; (where event is derived from the client.addEventHandler) 
try {

  await client.sendMessage(message.chatId, {
    message: "Downloading video...",
  });

  const video = message.video;

  var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("./myPath.mp4", { flags: "w" });

  try {
    const fileLocation = new Api.InputDocumentFileLocation({
      id: video.id,
      accessHash: video.accessHash,
      fileReference: video.fileReference,
      thumbSize: video.thumbs.[0].type
    });

    for await (const chunk of client.iterDownload({
      file: fileLocation,
      requestSize: 2048 * 1024,
    })) {
      console.log("Downloaded chunk of size", chunk.length);
      const canWrite = writeStream.write(chunk);

      if (!canWrite) {
        await new Promise((resolve) => writeStream.once("drain", resolve));
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error downloading video:", error);
  } finally {
    writeStream.end();
  }
}
// etc...


problem: Whenever the download is finished and saved to ./path.mp4 the resultant file is corrupt and cannot be used, but if I switch the path from ./path.mp4 to ./path.jpg the thumbnail of the video is saved properly... this probably means that the function I used (Api.InputDocumentFileLocation) is mainly to save photos...
I also tried:

Api.InputFileLocation and got error 400: LOCATION_INVALID.
Api.InputPhotoFileLocation and got error 400: FILE_REFERENCE_EXPIRED

Any method to stream videos into files in gramJS properly?

Did you try to compare the contents of file created with InputDocumentFileLocation with actual file, so you could know why it is corrupted?

@EstusFlask yes I did, it's cause it wrote a jpg file into an mp4 file
